# How to solve $\cos(\theta + angle)$ equation?

Tags: trigonometry

I can't seem to figure out how to solve an equation similar to the one below.

$$cos(\theta+\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

The steps I have taken so far are shown below. From there I would just solve for $\theta$, however after checking my answer with Woflram Alpha, I appear to have done something wrong.

$$\theta+\frac{\pi}{3}=\arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$$

Am I missing a step when solving this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step is ok, but it misses the "second" solution: $$\theta+\frac{\pi}{3}=\pm{arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}})$$
Move the $\pi/3$ over and you are done! (You may add the multiplicity of $2\pi$ if needed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite understand why it would be $\pm$, could you please explain that?

Comment: Remember that cosine is periodic and for any number in $(0, 1)$ one of the angles whose cosine is that number is plus while the other is minus. Check the unit circle!

Comment: @SeanRoberson Ahh yep I see. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(a+b) = \cos a\cos b - \sin a\sin b$$$$=\cos\theta\cos\frac\pi 3 - \sin\theta\sin\frac\pi 3$$

Try going off of this.